# Excel ODBC connection drops columns

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I'm using an Excel ODBC connection with Query Editor to just retrieve data from a view I have on MySQL. Excel is just ignoring one column that should contain only CHAR(7) which is calculated from other column. What can be happening here?

The query I'm sending is just `SELECT * FROM view`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is ensuring none of the fields is represented by MySQL as type `BLOB` and therefore is representable in Excel.